# How to interprete this probability problem

Tags: probability

I want to show the following:

> If $X$ is an integrable random variable then $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty} k\,\Bbb P(|X|>k)=0$

What does this mean or better what does this limit say? Sorry if I'm not precise enough, I just want to become a better understanding of the problem.

Comment: Another way to think of this is as follows: If we let $f(k) = P(|X| > k)$ (that is, $f(k)$ is the probability that (the absolute value of) $X$ exceeds $k$), then $f(k)$ is $o(1/k)$.  Informally, $f(k)$ goes to $0$ faster than $1/k$ does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is essentially a stronger form of Markov's inequality, which tells you that
$$ \mathbb{P}(|X|>k)\leq \frac{\mathbb{E}[|X|]}{k} $$
for all $k>0$. To prove it, fix $\varepsilon>0$ and choose a simple random variable $Y$ such that
$$ \mathbb{E}[|X-Y|]<\varepsilon$$
and let $M=||Y||_{\infty}$.
If $k>2M$, then
$$ \{|X|>k\}\subset \{|X-Y|>k-M\}$$ hence
$$ k\mathbb{P}(|X|>k)\leq k\mathbb{P}(|X-Y|>k-M)\leq \frac{k}{k-M}\mathbb{E}[|X-Y|]<\frac{k}{k-M}\varepsilon\leq 2\varepsilon$$
since $k>2M$.